# Jest external library use require('jquery') but return undefined

Tags: angular, jestjs

Hi there,

I am using [Jest-Preset-Angular](https://github.com/thymikee/jest-preset-angular) with Angular-CLI to test an Angular 4 application that uses [Materialize](https://github.com/Dogfalo/materialize) which depends on jQuery.

**The problem**

The problem is that Materialize extends jQuery and to do so it calls `require('jquery')` but it returns `undefined` when I run the tests with Jest.

```js
if (typeof(jQuery) === 'undefined') {
  var jQuery;
  // Check if require is a defined function.
  if (typeof(require) === 'function') {
    jQuery = $ = require('jquery');
  // Else use the dollar sign alias.
  } else {
    jQuery = $;
  }
}
```

**My actual setup**

I am mocking jQuery like this...

```js
import * as $ from 'jquery/dist/jquery';

Object.defineProperty(window, '$', { value: $ });
Object.defineProperty(window, 'jQuery', { value: $ });
```

And importing Materialize after mocking jQuery like this...

```js
import 'materialize-css/dist/js/materialize';
```

**My expectations**

As Materialize extends jQuery and the application components are using the extended methods, It needs to be correctly loaded (including jQuery) for tests not to fails.

Any help is greatly welcome and thanks in advance for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I feel silly but if anybody ever get the same problem, for me updating Jest-Preset-Angular to v2.0.5 and Jest-JUnit to v2.1.0 solved the problem.